# A better way to get only specific attributes from a Django queryset?

Tags: python, django

I have a model named Songs and one of its attributes is `'title'`.

Let's say I want to get a list of all the song titles stored in a database.

I could do:

```
titles = []

for song in Song.objects.all():
    titles.append(song.title)
```

Is there is a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Best variant: `Song.objects.values('title')`

Documentaion: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values

Answer (score 9):

**You can use [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to get the list of all the song titles.**

It will return list of tuples values. Each tuple contains the value from the respective field passed into the `values_list()` call.

```
Song.objects.values_list('title') 
[('title1',), ('title2',), ('title3',), (u'title4',)] # returns list of tuples
```

If you **pass in the `flat` parameter** set to `True`, it will return the  results as single values, rather than one-tuples.

```
Song.objects.values_list('title', flat=True) # pass 'flat' parameter
['title1', 'title2', 'title3', 'title4'] # returns list of titles
```

**I think this is what you intended to get in the first place.**

But remember, it is an error to pass in `flat` with more than one field.

You can also use [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#values) to get all the titles but it will return list of dictionaries with each dictionary representing an object, with the keys corresponding to the attribute names of model objects.

```
Song.objects.values('title') # using '.values'
[{'title': 'title1'}, {'title': 'title2'}, {'title': 'title3'}, {'title': 'title4'}] # returns list of dictionaries
```

Comment: wow thanks a bunch. I was wondering how to get around the dictionary return value, and this works like a charm.

Comment: Great! Happy to help. :)