# django dynamic query set filtering with using string from URL

Tags: django, django-models, django-filter

is there any way we can filter the queryset dynamically i.e we have a two string value from the url and search the model where first string is an  **attribute** of the model and get all the objects containing second string in that particular attribute

Comment: Use [**django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package

Comment: If you need just one attribute, then django-filter will be a too complex solution for a simple problem. But if you can get multiple attributes at a time then you can go ahead with django-filter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic filter in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47182481/dynamic-filter-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just need to follow this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31857167/a-better-way-to-get-only-specific-attributes-from-a-django-queryset) and adapt it to your case

```
Model.objects.values('attribute', 'id') # using '.values'
[{'attribute': 'some attribute', 'id': 1 }, {'attribute': 'some 3', 'id': 2}, {'attribute': 'something', 'id': 3}, {'attribute': 'some some', 'id': 4}] # returns list of dictionaries
```

Filter or search the list of dictionaries with your "second string" and make a new query with the ids. 
You can adapt this [one](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-dictionary-matching-value-in-list/)

```
Model.objects.filter(id__in=object_ids)
```

---

or use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35563317/can-i-dynamically-pass-a-list-of-arguments-to-a-python-function-with-predefined)

```
filterExpresion = attribute+'__contains'
dynamicFilter = {filterExpresion: secondString} 
Model.objects.filter(**dynamicFilter)
```